# Best way to alternate constraints on two dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two dropdown selects that have the same values. I am building a converter from the source (left) unit to the destination (right) unit . It doesn't make sense to convert to and from like units. I know how to add an event on a dropdown select to remove the selected option from the alternate box but I am unclear on writing this to produce the best UI experience. Give the following trimmed case:

```
<select name="srcUnit" id="srcUnit">
    <option value="Unit 1">Unit 1</option>
    <option value="Unit 2">Unit 2</option>
    <option value="Unit 3">Unit 3</option>
</select>

<select name="dstUnit" id="dstUnit">
    <option value="Unit 1">Unit 1</option>
    <option value="Unit 2">Unit 2</option>
    <option value="Unit 3">Unit 3</option>
</select>
```

What might be a best practice for approaching this? If you choose a source of "Unit 2" how should destination react, remove it? Then I need a reset button, or if you choose "Unit 2" in destination as well, bounce source to something else (that seems worse and intuitive)?

Forget about this and just validate on submit?

Comment: Sounds like a question more suited to http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the new value on each dropdown change event.

If the value is also selected in the other dropdown, move the value of the other dropdown to next (or default) option.

To give the user a clue that he should not select the same value twice, gray out the values that are already select in the other dropdown.

I have written the code for you, here is an executable snippet:

```js
$("#srcUnit, #dstUnit").change(function(){
    /*Detect wether we have srcUnit or dstUnit */
    if($(this).attr("id") == "srcUnit"){var otherUnit = "dstUnit";}
    else{var otherUnit = "srcUnit";}
    /*Save new Value*/
    var newVal = $(this).children("option:selected" ).val();
    /*Select next option in other dropdown if it's old value was selected*/
    if(newVal == $("#"+otherUnit+" option:selected").val()){  
       $('#'+otherUnit+' option:selected').removeAttr('selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
    /*Update UI*/
    $('#'+otherUnit+' option').removeClass("disabled");
    $('#'+otherUnit+' option[value="'+newVal+'"]').addClass("disabled");
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="srcUnit" id="srcUnit">
    <option value="Unit 1" selected>Unit 1</option>
    <option value="Unit 2">Unit 2</option>
    <option value="Unit 3">Unit 3</option>
</select>

<select name="dstUnit" id="dstUnit">
    <option value="Unit 1" class="disabled">Unit 1</option>
    <option value="Unit 2" selected>Unit 2</option>
    <option value="Unit 3">Unit 3</option>
</select>
```

---

*I edited my answer to better fit the question, old Answer:*

Use the HTML 5 disabled attribute.

```
<select name="srcUnit" id="srcUnit">
    <option value="Unit 1">Unit 1</option>
    <option value="Unit 2" selected>Unit 2</option>
    <option value="Unit 3">Unit 3</option>
</select>

<select name="dstUnit" id="dstUnit">
    <option value="Unit 1">Unit 1</option>
    <option value="Unit 2" disabled>Unit 2</option>
    <option value="Unit 3">Unit 3</option>
</select>
```

Read more and try out here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp

Subscribe to the onchange event of the dropdowns with javascript and toggle the attribute as needed.

Comment: Well, I had stated I was familiar with the event and how to disable an option. The question was a more a UI best experience approach given the description of usage.

Comment: you could use style="color:#ccc;" instead of the disabled attribute and check via JS if both dropdowns have the same value selected, if someone selects the grey entry the other dropdown can reset to it's default value(or a second one if the default is selected). This way you don't need a reset button.

Comment: You should write this an answer, that is actually intuitive and unobtrusive, I will run with this.